# Large files end up corrupted when copying to a compressed NTFS3 win drive

Tags: windows, ssd, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I have two SSDs, one Linux, one Windows 11, and an HDD. I can copy normal-sized files just fine to each other, generally they are under 2GB.

Recently, I tried to copy a big file (32GB) from Linux (ext4) over to the Windows (ntfs3) and no matter how many times I tried, it always ended up with a mismatching md5sum (but consistent over every try).

I could copy to HDD, then boot into windows, and copy into Windows from the HDD just fine, as well.

After a while, I realized if I disable compression, I can copy directly to the Windows SSD.

I was wondering if this issue rests on the Linux side, e.g. it's not mounting the Windows SSD with proper flags or something, hence why file ends up being corrupted. Thoughts?

Comment: hibernation / fast boot is disabled on both sides?

Comment: @frostschutz I press Shift when turning off windows, otherwise I wouldn't even be able to mount the SSD on linux side. I think that releases the SSD.

Comment: Please try ntfs-3g. NTFS3 is *still* experimental.